# How to preserve ownership with cmake "install directory" directive?

Tags: permissions, cmake, directory, installation, ownership

USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS preserves the permissions as expected:

```
install(
  DIRECTORY dir/
  DESTINATION dest
  USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS
)
```

However, the ownership of the files is not preserved when I run

```
sudo make install
```

Am I missing something, or there's no way of accomplishing it cleanly with CMake?

EDIT:

- cmake version 3.5.2
- operating system arch linux

I came up with the simplest example I could think of to reproduce the issue and still, the same is happening.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/to_install
        DESTINATION $ENV{HOME}
        USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS)
```

Then I run:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
sudo make install
```

The original permissions are:

```
.──[drwxr-xr-x guicc   ]  test-cmake
   ├── [-rw-r--r-- guicc   ]  CMakeLists.txt
   └── [drwxr-xr-x guicc   ]  to_install
       ├── [-rw-r--r-- guicc   ]  file1.txt
       └── [-rw-r--r-- guicc   ]  file2.txt
```

While the resulting permissions are the following:

```
.──[drwxr-xr-x root   ] to_install
   ├── [-rw-r--r-- root    ]  file1.txt
   └── [-rw-r--r-- root    ]  file2.txt
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like a bug. What are the permissions of your source directory, what are these of the installed directory? What version of CMake do you use? What operating system? This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've edited my question to be more specific.